# Disable animation for nested ContentControl

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-8, transition

I want to disable the EntrenceThemeAnimation for one of my elements. I have a Grid that sets this animation to all it's children(I think it's default for a page). Is it possible to disable this animation for a ContentControl that is a children of this grid?

I've tried the following but it does not seem to work.

**Content**

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
...
<!-- no animations for this element -->
<ContentControl x:Name="Background" Content="Tabstagram" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource Background}">
    <ContentControl.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection/>
    </ContentControl.Transitions>
    <ContentControl.ContentTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection/>
    </ContentControl.ContentTransitions>
</ContentControl>
```

**Styles**

```
<Style x:Key="LayoutRootStyle" TargetType="Panel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="ChildrenTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Background" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                        <TransitionCollection/>
                    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                    <Grid.Transitions>
                        <TransitionCollection/>
                    </Grid.Transitions>
                    <Rectangle IsHitTestVisible="False" StrokeThickness="75" Margin="0" Fill="#FFC1C1C1"/>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to break your CC out of its parent grid for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following in the LayoutRoot grid for my page and it correctly disables the entrance theme transition:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection/>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
```

Notice, though, that I'm overriding the transitions for a panel that's using **LayoutRootStyle** and I'm doing it in the page rather than a resource.

It could be that these animations flow downward from the first control they're enabled on regardless of whether or not child controls have them disabled. You could try putting both panels at the same level of the UI hierarchy (peers rather than one nested inside the other) and see if that fixes it.